# How to know if a point is inside a 2D cone (sector of a circle)?

Tags: java

I want to see if there is a method to understand that a point is inside a sector of a circle?

thanks.

Comment: What do you understand by a [cone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone)? [circular sector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector)?

Comment: Please be more specific. The more information you provide, the better we can assist you. Give us examples of your code. What have you tried? What isn't working? Are you getting any errors? If yes, what are they? etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Down voted as no research effort described, or indication of technology.

Answer (score 4):

Convert your point to polar coordinates and then compare the point's r to the circle's radius and the point's theta to the arc describing your sector. 
[Polar Coordinate System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system)

Answer (score -2):

Use the distance formula.

```
if(distance from point to circle center < radius) {/*this means point is in circle*/}
```

You can use trig to find the angle.

Comment: not really, it doesn't mean the point is inside a certain sector. 
This just tells the point is inside the circle.

Comment: @RobinChander Then he can use trig. He did not put in much effort, neither did i.